# How can I run multiple obfuscated services on a machine?

Tags: configuration, obfsproxy, openvpn

I would like to add an OpenVPN service (for personal use) to a machine I already have an obfuscated Tor bridge running on (for shared use).  I would like the option to access this VPN through obfsproxy, while still allowing for Tor to have its own managed obfsproxy (both running obfs3).

Is this a problem?  Do I simply fire up a new, non-managed obfsproxy instance for the VPN?

Comment: I would suspect it's just that easy. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

As long as each obfsproxy instance binds a unique port, you can have as many of them as you have the resources to run.